# How to filter the email addresses to be used in the "send email" script step

Tags: filemaker

In FM18, I have two tables: "documents" and "recipients".

The "documents" table has (among others) the "owner" attribute, while the "recipients" has the attributes "department" and "emailAddress".

​

I'm working on a script that sends an email message to all the email addresses included in the records having `recipients::department = documents::owner`.

​

The script is executed when clicking on a button in a layout related to the "documents" table.

​

In the "send email" option form, I have selected "Collect addresses across found set" but now, what should I put in the calculation?

Attached you can find some script (they are in Italian) and the relationship screenshots.

[image] [image]

Comment: Any ideas how I can limit the number of sent emails just to one?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am somewhat confused by the relationship (?) you describe:

```
recipients::emailAddress = documents::owner
```

How many recipients can be related to a single document? It seems like it should be only one.

Assuming it IS a relationship, and that a document CAN have multiple related recipients, you can do any one of the following:

1. Select the **One email using data from the current record** option.
   Deselect the **Collect addresses across found set** option. For the
   **To** address, select `Specify Calculation…` and enter either:

   ```
   List ( recipients::emailAddress )
   ```

   or:

   ```
   Substitute ( List ( recipients::emailAddress ) ; ¶ ; ";" )
   ```
2. Make your script do:

   ```
   Set Variable [ $message ; "Your message here" ]
   Go to Related Record [ From recipients; Show only related records ]
   Send Mail [ To: recipients::emailAddress (collect addresses); Message: $message ]
   ```

---

Caveat: much of this is untested (I don't send mails from Filemaker).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated the relationship, In `documents` the `owner` is a department. Then I need from `recipients` all the email addresses in the records having the `departments` equal to the `owner` of the document.

Comment: My answer is still the same.

Comment: Thanks, how do I set `recipients::emailAddress (collect addresses)`? Should I add it to the `calculation` field?

Comment: The script seems almost fine. It sends the email to the correct addresses. However, it sends an email for each record in the table and not only for the current record. Thanks